# Change total length unit using calculate geometry

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I want to change the total length from decimal degree to meter. How? the length was disable.

[image: calculate geometry]

Answer (score 1):

As you are in geographic coordinate system the length property will always be in decimal degrees. Change your coordinate system to projected instead of geographic coordinate system. By doing this, the length property will automatically be enabled and you will be able to calculate length.